# Questions about connecting a JTAG ARM 10-pin connector to a TM412x board

Tags: microcontroller, connector, soldering, debugging, jtag

I have a TM4C12x board which I want to debug over JTAG. This board does not come with a pin header attached to the JTAG pins, so I need to solder it myself. I have a couple of questions about this:

**Debug probe**: I want to use the SEGGER tools (`JLinkExe`, `JLinkGDBServer`) so I'm going to buy a [SEGGER JLink EDU mini](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Segger-Microcontroller/80891?qs=sGAEpiMZZMu3sxpa5v1qrl%2FCvv%2FAKsiqz2V3YOhWPBg%3D) plus an [ARM-JTAG-20-10](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Olimex-Ltd/ARM-JTAG-20-10?qs=DUTFWDROaMbVQp3WoAdijQ%3D%3D&vip=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwhvf6BRCkARIsAGl1GGixklH_8PLMvez9KHiaPOQ1WBLyPkK0sR_TnCQODjo0PZ_JCRXP9zMaAk83EALw_wcB). My intention is to use an ARM 10-pin JTAG interface only, I want the adaptor just in case.

**Soldering and connecting**: I'm following the TI guidelines about how to connect the JTAG interface. However, it's not clear to me what to do with the RST_N pin, let me explain:

This is a schematics about how to perform the connections:
[image]

`However, below this schematics I find this:`

[image]

In the schematics, there is no connection from `EXTDBG` to `GND` and the `RST_N` pin is connected to the ARM JTAG interface. In addition, there are several resistors.

On the other hand, the steps in the second image don't mention anything about resistors, however the do mentiong that `EXTDBG` must be connected to `GND`. In addition, it mentions that `RST_N` must be connected to the `RESET` on the debug probe, however the `RESET` pin on the board (which I'm assuming is `RST_N`, see more details below) is not wired in the picture.

**Questions:**

- Then, do I need to connect the resistors in the schematics myself?
- It seems that connecting the `RST_N` pin is required even though the guide doesn't mention it, correct? I need to be able to reset the MCU from `gdb` by executing `monitor reset` when ttached to `JLinkGDBServer`. I guess this pin is required to do this, right? (I mean, the `RST_N` pin probably resets the MCU)
- In my board (TM4C123GXL), there are no pins called `RST_N`, there is a `RESET` pin near the JTAG ones though. Are these two pins the same one? (see below)

**TM4C123GXL top view**
The `RESET` pin I mentioned above is in the top right. Is it `RST_N`?
[image]

The full TI document is [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj86c7soObrAhXCoXEKHXsiArQQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fe2echina.ti.com%2Fcfs-file%2F__key%2Ftelligent-evolution-components-attachments%2F00-96-00-00-00-11-70-81%2FUsing-TM4C12x-Devices-Over-JTAG-Interface.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1oqPyB6LZU7HPXIRKkY9NZ)

Comment: I would just wire it up like it says in Figure 10 and see how it goes, honestly. It's not likely to be harmful, worst case it doesn't work.

Comment: You already have a debug interface on that board, save yourself cost and headache by using that one.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using the TI code composer. The only free tool I have found to debug this board is openocd and it doesn't work very well (can't reset the MCU for instance)

Comment: Then fix the openocd configuration to use hardware reset.  One can quite clearly see in the picture that the reset trace runs to the debug adapter MCU.  In terms of your question, a CPU reset input is not part of JTAG, but something outside of it which could also be used; or not used in favor of a soft or commanded reset - though as you may be seeing, that won't work in the case of some suspend modes, or (re/mis)configuration of the jtag pins to another non-jtag mode.